# Python saving execution time when multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, time, queue

I am having a problem when multithreading and using queues in python 2.7. I want the code with threads to take about half as long as the one without, but I think I'm doing something wrong. I am using a simple looping technique for the fibonacci sequence to best show the problem.

Here is the code without threads and queues. It printed 19.9190001488 seconds as its execution time.

```
import time

start_time = time.time()

def fibonacci(priority, num):
    if num == 1 or num == 2:
        return 1
    a = 1
    b = 1
    for i in range(num-2):
        c = a + b
        b = a
        a = c
    return c

print fibonacci(0, 200000)
print fibonacci(1, 100)
print fibonacci(2, 200000)
print fibonacci(3, 2)

print("%s seconds" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Here is the code with threads and queues. It printed 21.7269999981 seconds as its execution time.

```
import time

start_time = time.time()

from Queue import *
from threading import *

numbers = [200000,100,200000,2]
q = PriorityQueue()
threads = []

def fibonacci(priority, num):
    if num == 1 or num == 2:
        q.put((priority, 1))
        return
    a = 1
    b = 1
    for i in range(num-2):
        c = a + b
        b = a
        a = c
    q.put((priority, c))
    return

for i in range(4):
    priority = i
    num = numbers[i]
    t = Thread(target = fibonacci, args = (priority, num))
    threads.append(t)

#print threads

for t in threads:
    t.start()

for t in threads:
    t.join()

while not q.empty():
    ans = q.get()
    q.task_done()
    print ans[1]

print("%s seconds" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

What I thought would happen is the multithreaded code takes half as long as the code without threads. Essentially I thought that all the threads work at the same time, so the 2 threads calculating the fibonacci number at 200,000 would finish at the same time, so execution is about twice as fast as the code without threads. Apparently that's not what happened. Am I doing something wrong? I just want to execute all threads at the same time, print in the order that they started and the thread that takes the longest time is pretty much the execution time.

**EDIT:**

I updated my code to use processes, but now the results aren't being printed. Only  an execution time of 0.163000106812 seconds is showing. Here is the new code:

```
import time

start_time = time.time()

from Queue import *
from multiprocessing import *

numbers = [200000,100,200000,2]
q = PriorityQueue()
processes = []

def fibonacci(priority, num):
    if num == 1 or num == 2:
        q.put((priority, 1))
        return
    a = 1
    b = 1
    for i in range(num-2):
        c = a + b
        b = a
        a = c
    q.put((priority, c))
    return

for i in range(4):
    priority = i
    num = numbers[i]
    p = Process(target = fibonacci, args = (priority, num))
    processes.append(p)

#print processes

for p in processes:
    p.start()

for p in processes:
    p.join()

while not q.empty():
    ans = q.get()
    q.task_done()
    print ans[1]

print("%s seconds" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Comment: Which OS are you using? Windows?

Answer (score 0):

You've run in one of the basic limiting factors of the CPython implementation, the [Global Interpreter Lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Interpreter_Lock) or GIL. Effectively this serializes your program, your threads will take turns executing. One thread will own the GIL, while the other threads will wait for the GIL to come free.

One solution would to be use separate processes. Each process would have its own GIL so would execute in parallel. Probably the easiest way to do this is to use Python's [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) module as replacement for the threading module.